# python dynamic programming question of coin change

Tags: dynamic

I just started learning dynamic programming and came across this formula for calculating the minimum change problem:

```
P = total money
d(i) - coin denomination

C|p| = {0, if p = 0
       {min(i):d(i)<p {1+C|p-d(i)|}, if p > 0
```

Can someone please explain where the 1 + C|p-d(i) comes from, why is it '1+'?
Also why are we deleting each coin demonination from the total value p?

Thx in advance

Comment: You use one (`1`) coin with a certain denomination and add to that the number of coins you need to get the rest, which is total minus the denomination of the coin you used